# Flexslider IE Issue - Loading images below active image

Tags: flexslider

I'm having an issue with Flexslider not working properly in Internet Explorer - it's working fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

When the page loads it loads the first image ok. However, the next image appears below the current on as it fades out then jumps up.

You're probably best off seeing it in action;

http://www.philippacraddock.com/index_test.html

Annoying the hell out of me (how many hours have I wasted pandering to internet explorer's precious foibles over the years...) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers in advance.